# Sending array value as parameter retrofit android

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

I need to send a parameter as array in retrofit.
This is the required key-value:

```
 "country":["Canada","India"]
```

Now, when i pass it, It changes the whole array into string.
This is how i am passing the value:

```
"country":"["Canada", "India"]"
```

The code i am using is here:

```
ArrayList<String> countriedAplied = new ArrayList<>();

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try
{
  jsonObject.put("country", countriedAplied);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ArrayList<String> countriedAplied = new ArrayList<>();

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

            jsonArray.put(countriedAplied);
        try {
            jsonObject.put("Country",jsonArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject gsonObject = new JsonObject();
gsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonObject.toString());
sendtoDB(gsonObject);
```

Comment: Hey Adnan,
Still having the same issue.

[Reference Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FqyaUCUyc7rb5MePRw9z_bDRo0oDUhdS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: check updated answer